# Why when i use hover with div its also hover next to my text?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*selector {property: value;} */
 * { text-align: center;}
body {
 background-image: url(photo-1511798616182-aab3698ac53e.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
 
      color:rgba(255, 101, 101);}
   
   
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid rgba(43, 109, 18,0.6);
    cursor:pointer; }
.thetitle {font-family: georgia;
           font-style:italic;}



a {
  color:rgba(255, 255, 170, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
}   
a:hover {
  color:rgba(212, 106, 106);
text-decoration: none;}

span{display: inline;}


h3:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}

.regi:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}
#regi3:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}
#regi4:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}
#regi5:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}
#regi6:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}
.regi7{display: inline;}
#regi7:hover {color:rgba(229, 30, 35);}

.regi {margin: 8px 0;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register.css">
</head>
<body>
<header><h1><a href="file:///C:/Users/Yonatan/Desktop/Progrems/web/register.html">Registertion page</h1></a></header>
<form method="post"> <div id="registertionpage"> <!-- change to post later-->
 <div for="nickname" class="regi">Nickname:</div>
   <input type="text" name="nickname" required>
 <div class="regi">First Name:</div>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
 <div class="regi">Last Name:</div>  
   <input type="text" name="lastname" required>
 <div class="regi">Choose your password:</div>  
   <input type="password" name="password" minlength="10" required>
 <div class="regi">Email adress: </div>  
   <input type="email" name="email" required>
 <div class="regi">Birthday: </div>  
   <time><input type="date" name="birthdate"required></time>
 <div class="regi">Gender:</div>  
   <div id="regi3"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="si"required> Male</div></br>
   <div id="regi4"> <input type="radio"name="gender" value="nei"> Female</div></br>
   <div id="regi5"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div></br>
  <div class="regi">Do u agree to the website rules?</div>
  <div id="regi6"><input type="checkbox" name="webrules" value="webrules"required> yes</div>
  <div class="regi">Wanna get news?</div>
   <div id="regi7"> <input type="radio" name="news" value="yes"> yes</div></br>
   <div id="regi7"> <input type="radio" name="news" value="no"> no</div>
   <div class="regi">Select your style:</div> <!-- change website theme with it -->
   <select name="theme">
   <option value="white" name="white">white</option>
   <option value="red" name="red" >red</option>
   <option value="black" name="black" >black</option>
   <option value="green" name="green" >hentai</option>
 
   </select><br><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Reegister"> <input type="reset"><br><br><br>


  </div></form><br>



<nav><a href="file:///C:/Users/Yonatan/Desktop/Progrems/web/webcod.html">Back</a></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

So i tried using `hover` with `span` and `lable` because i saw that when i do that its only hover on the text but the problem with that is that if i do that for some reason the `{text-align:center;}` doesn't work and when i use `div` and `p` it does work but the problem with this is that its also hover near the text and i have no idea what the problem is.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the hover is triggering beside your text is because the div (`.regi`) is a block level element that is occupying the whole width.

Aside from that, you can do a lot to simplify your markup. Here's an example showing how you can clean this up using only the Gender radio button as an example. You can learn from this an apply the same method to the rest of your elements.

The reason for the `wrap` divs I added here is to shrinkwrap the floated radio button + label. In your design, you have the radio button on the left and the label on the right, but semantically it's best to have the label appear first in the markup. So to achieve the same result visually, I floated the radio button left, floated the label right, and put them in a div which is also floated to shrink wrap it.

```css
.wrap {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  float: left;
}

label {
  float: right;
}

label:hover {
  color: rgba(229, 30, 35);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="registertionpage">
      <div class="wrap">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="si" required>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap">
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="si" required>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap">
        <label for="other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="si" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</html>
```